# From XLS into CSV - macro Save As visual option

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am glad to be here with great programmers and hope I will learn a lot. I am also new in this kind of programming so I am sorry for any inconvenience.

I am using the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) code below to transfer my files from `XLS` into `CSV`. After it translates the `xls` file into `csv` format, it saves automatically my newly created `csv` file in the same directory as my original `xls` file.

I would like to have a **`Save As`** option for my `csv` filename

Thank you in advance.

```
' ---------------------- Directory Choosing Helper Functions -----------------------
' Excel and VBA do not provide any convenient directory chooser or file chooser
' dialogs, but these functions will provide a reference to a system DLL
' with the necessary capabilities
Private Type BROWSEINFO ' used by the function GetFolderName
    hOwner As Long
    pidlRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long

Function GetFolderName(Msg As String) As String
' returns the name of the folder selected by the user
Dim bInfo As BROWSEINFO, path As String, r As Long
Dim X As Long, pos As Integer
    bInfo.pidlRoot = 0& ' Root folder = Desktop
    If IsMissing(Msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Select a folder."
        ' the dialog title
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = Msg ' the dialog title
    End If
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1 ' Type of directory to return
    X = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo) ' display the dialog
    ' Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal X, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetFolderName = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetFolderName = ""
    End If
End Function
'---------------------- END Directory Chooser Helper Functions ----------------------

Public Sub DoTheExport()
Dim FName As Variant
Dim Sep As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim csvPath As String

Sep = ";"

csvPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

Dim brojac As Integer
brojac = 0
For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
If brojac > 0 Then Exit For
    wsSheet.Activate
        nFileNum = FreeFile
        Open csvPath & "\" & _
          Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5) & ".csv" For Output As #nFileNum    ' wsSheet.Name
        ExportToTextFile CStr(nFileNum), Sep, False
        Close nFileNum
    brojac = brojac + 1
Next wsSheet

End Sub

Public Sub ExportToTextFile(nFileNum As Integer, _
Sep As String, SelectionOnly As Boolean)

Dim WholeLine As String
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim StartCol As Integer
Dim EndCol As Integer
Dim CellValue As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo EndMacro:

If SelectionOnly = True Then
With Selection
StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
End With
Else
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
End With
End If

For RowNdx = StartRow To EndRow
WholeLine = ""
For ColNdx = StartCol To EndCol
If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
CellValue = ""
Else
CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
End If
WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
Next ColNdx
WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - Len(Sep))
Print #nFileNum, WholeLine
Next RowNdx

EndMacro:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Probably the problem is here. This part of code has to be re-writen or corrected.
This is the main function which calls other ones.

```
Public Sub DoTheExport()
Dim FName As Variant
Dim Sep As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim csvPath As String

Sep = ";"

csvPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

Dim brojac As Integer
brojac = 0
For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
If brojac > 0 Then Exit For
    wsSheet.Activate
        nFileNum = FreeFile
        Open csvPath & "\" & _
          Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5) & ".csv" For Output As #nFileNum    ' wsSheet.Name
        ExportToTextFile CStr(nFileNum), Sep, False
        Close nFileNum
    brojac = brojac + 1
Next wsSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code appears to be only saving the first sheet of the ActiveWorkbook as a CSV (the `brojac` test exits after sheet1). You can change this line `Open csvPath & "\" & _
          Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5) & ".csv" For Output As #nFileNum` to change your file save path

Comment: I know all of that. The problem is I don't know how to change it because I don't know commands to do that. I need that after it makes my CSV, it openes me Save As option, that I chose where to save that CSV file.

Comment: Fixed below. Added faster CSV code sample to boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This updated code gives you a SaveAs name option (with a default as *WorkbookName.csv*)
2. More efficient code using variant arrays to make your csv below.

These are the three key updated lines:

```
strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5), "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")
If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Open strFileName For Output As #nFileNum
```

**updated code**

```
Public Sub DoTheExport()
Dim FName As Variant
Dim Sep As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim csvPath As String
Dim strFileName As String

Sep = ";"
csvPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

Dim brojac As Long
brojac = 0
For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
If brojac > 0 Then Exit For
    wsSheet.Activate
        nFileNum = FreeFile
        strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5), "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")
        If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
        Open strFileName For Output As #nFileNum
        ExportToTextFile CStr(nFileNum), Sep, False
        Close nFileNum
    brojac = brojac + 1
Next wsSheet
End Sub
```

**more efficient csv code**

From [Creating and Writing to a CSV File Using Excel VBA](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_3509-Creating-and-Writing-to-a-CSV-File-Using-Excel-VBA.html)

1. This code must be run from a regular VBA Code Module.  Otherwise the code will cause an error if users try to run it from the `ThisWorkbook` or Sheet Code panes given the usage of `Const`.
2. It is worth noting that the `ThisWorkbook` and Sheet code sections should be reserved for Event coding only, "normal" VBA should be run from standard Code Modules.
3. Please note that for purposes of the sample code, the file path of the CSV output file is "hard-coded" as:  `C:\test\myfile.csv` at the top of the code.  You will probably want to set the output file programmatically, for instance as a function parameter.
4. As mentioned earlier;   For example purposes, this code *TRANSPOSES COLUMNS AND ROWS*; that is, the output file contains one CSV row for each column in the selected range.  Normally, CSV output would be row-by-row, echoing the layout visible on screen, but I    wanted to demonstrate that generating the output by using VBA code provides options beyond what is available by, for instance, using   the `Save As... CSV Text` menu option.

**code**

```
Const sFilePath = "C:\test\myfile.csv"
Const strDelim = ","
Sub CreateCSV_Output()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim X
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim strTmp As String
    Dim lFnum As Long

    lFnum = FreeFile
    Open sFilePath For Output As lFnum

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'test that sheet has been used
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            'only multi-cell ranges can be written to a 2D array
            If rng1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                X = ws.UsedRange.Value2
                'The code TRANSPOSES COLUMNS AND ROWS by writing strings column by column
                For lCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
                    'write initial value outside the loop
                     strTmp = IIf(InStr(X(1, lCol), strDelim) > 0, """" & X(1, lCol) & """", X(1, lCol))
                    For lRow = 2 To UBound(X, 1)
                        'concatenate long string & (short string with short string)
                        strTmp = strTmp & (strDelim & IIf(InStr(X(lRow, lCol), strDelim) > 0, """" & X(lRow, lCol) & """", X(lRow, lCol)))
                    Next lRow
                    'write each line to CSV
                    Print #lFnum, strTmp
                Next lCol
            Else
                Print #lFnum, IIf(InStr(ws.UsedRange.Value, strDelim) > 0, """" & ws.UsedRange.Value & """", ws.UsedRange.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    Close lFnum
    MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub CreateCSV_FSO()
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objTF
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim strTmp As String
    Dim lFnum As Long

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile(sFilePath, True, False)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'test that sheet has been used
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            'only multi-cell ranges can be written to a 2D array
            If rng1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                X = ws.UsedRange.Value2
                'The code TRANSPOSES COLUMNS AND ROWS by writing strings column by column
                For lCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
                    'write initial value outside the loop
                    strTmp = IIf(InStr(X(1, lCol), strDelim) > 0, """" & X(1, lCol) & """", X(1, lCol))
                    For lRow = 2 To UBound(X, 1)
                        'concatenate long string & (short string with short string)
                        strTmp = strTmp & (strDelim & IIf(InStr(X(lRow, lCol), strDelim) > 0, """" & X(lRow, lCol) & """", X(lRow, lCol)))
                    Next lRow
                    'write each line to CSV
                    objTF.writeline strTmp
                Next lCol
            Else
                objTF.writeline IIf(InStr(ws.UsedRange.Value, strDelim) > 0, """" & ws.UsedRange.Value & """", ws.UsedRange.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    objTF.Close
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: That is what I was looking about. It means that I need this kind of command: Application.GetSaveAsFilename. I did not know for this command. Thank you Sir. I appreciate your help indeed.